# Need help arraylist game

Tags: c#, console

Ok. So this is my first post (just joined). This is a school console app due in 2.5 weeks (NOT LOOKING FOR THE ANSWER!). Its a farmer game. My question is how do I (using an arrayList) to get my app to look like this (only the words, the "graphics" can wait) so that when the user selects to move one it ends up on the other side? I know a bit of C# && programming in general, but this is proving a MAJOR challenge! Lol. I love it but now I need help. I've worked on it for two full days; from 11 am to 11:30 pm but cant find out how. I know how to add and remove from the list, just don't know how to place them on another line after being selected. My codes a little messy, but if you want me to provide I will. A lot of methods I was trying are commented out. I have 5 classes, I just try to stay ahead on the C# hmwk because it's the most challenging.

Happy coding!

this is how it should start!
[farm pic start](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYTLK.png)

this is how the result looks!
[farm pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3Ltb.png)

Comment: My question is how do I (using an arrayList) to get my app to look like this ... this ???

Comment: I meant respond to user input like this. Move one arraylist word from one side to the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could take any number of approaches.  Likely the simplest would be to maintain two lists, one for the north shore and one for the south.

When you choose the item to move, you search for it in the list of the side where the farmer is, remove it from that list, and add it to the opposite side's list (along with moving the farmer).

Comment: Thanks! I finally got it!! :)